# Where is the location of the preset files on the splash screen?

Tags: interface

[image]
I want to be able to make custom presets and place them here on the splash screen. Is that possible?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[batFINGER got it this is what i was looking for.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html)